# JQuery-ui, auto hide dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, settimeout

I have a dynamic element that is converted to a dialog widget. i want it to disappear automatically.

This code is not working.

```
$("<div>...</div>").dialog({
  open : function(eve, ui) {
    var item = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(item) {
      item.dialog('close')
      }, 
    6000);
  }
});
```

Comment: try removing item as parm to the innermost function. just write function() {...}. The param overshadows the previously defined variable item.

Comment: I did @CBroe - not working

Comment: You are correct @Godisemo - but still, not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple problems - Your selector looked wrong.. also, you were trying to pass "item" to the settimeout which was overwriting your item = this.. also $(this) is what you meant by setting item=this;

```
 $("div").dialog({
  open : function(eve, ui) {
   var item = $(this);
     window.setTimeout(function() {
       item.dialog('close');
     }, 
     6000);
  }
});
```

Heres a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/qZggc/

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
$("<div id='mydialog'>...</div>").dialog({
  open : function(eve, ui) {
    window.setTimeout(function(item) {
      $('#mydialog').dialog('close');
      }, 
    6000);
  }
});
```

Here is working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/140/)**